App Stuck in Review on Google Play Store for Extended Periods, Unable to Reach Support
I've encountered a frustrating situation with my app on the Google Play Store. After publishing it, the app has been stuck in review for over one and a half months without any indication of approval or rejection. In an attempt to resolve this, I deleted the app and created a new one, but the issue persists, nearing another month of waiting.
I've exhausted all avenues of support—chat support always shows agents as busy, and the call support displays an error message stating "something went wrong." I've also raised a ticket, but it remains in progress without any updates.
Has anyone else faced a similar situation? If so, how did you manage to escalate the issue and get a resolution? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Sorry buddy, I can only say I'm having the same issues as you. Didn't found a solution yet.

Me too, apparently Google support page mentioned it's normal. Just bad luck. Resubmit will only put you back into the queue and unfortunately I had to push twice before they even got a chance to approve the previous. Pathetic.

I am also facing same issue from last 30 days, how did you solved that long time review issue.

We had an app in-review for a month+. Support kept telling us to keep waiting and that everything was fine. But we later found out that the account owner for our google developer account had an email in their inbox from google asking for additional information about the app. Google asked about 3rd party libraries and a description of what the app does. Pretty generic form. After we replied with that information our app was approved in 3 days. This was our initial production release to the store so it might be a one-time thing.
Our second submission has been in review for 2 weeks. I'm fearful there's another issue with our account that support isn't knowledgable about. So far I've been told to keep waiting...
Hope this helps someone

Thanks for your input, unfortunately that wasn't my case.
How is your 2nd submission going? My submission is currently stuck from 10th May :/

I emailed support and let them know it was not acceptable. They esculated my case and it was approved later that night. Our next two reviews have only taken 3-4 hours for approvals. Best of luck!

I've tried this already but unfortunately they are not replying to my support case :( I'll try pushing more for an update! Do you mind  sharing which contact form and/or email you used? Thanks

Just for the records, after several weeks and several support emails, they told me to submit a new update. I did it, and after a few hours the app was approved. Unfortunately, no one from the support team was able to tell us (or they could not share it, I don't know) what happened to avoid it again in the future.
